# How to explain that sitecore is returning item in language that is not created?

Tags: sitecore

I'm having an item that is defined in Dutch language, it looks like following:
[image]

When I attempt to find this item by querying it's parent I can not find it.

```cs
 rootTagItem.Axes.GetDescendants() ....
```

Looking at Immediate window I can tell that parent contains the item but in English which leaves me puzzled?!

```cs
rootTagItem.Axes.GetDescendants()
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[23]

Veehouderij-Varkens (en#1@web), id: {ED94B438-722B-498B-9499-84F749BB8429}
Database: "web"
Id: "{ED94B438-722B-498B-9499-84F749BB8429}"
Language: "en"
Name: "Veehouderij-Varkens"
Version: "1"
```

How can we explain that item is returned in English version despite the fact that English version is not defined (see image) ?

Marek's response was accepted because he provided the link that explains it.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using? Are you using Language fallback?

Comment: I'm using version 8, not sure if I'm using language fallback, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how Sitecore works.

When there are other language versions of this item, Sitecore will return this item even without any version in your language.

What you need to do is to check the `.Versions.Count()` like that:

```cs
rootTagItem.Axes.GetDescendants().Where(d => d.Versions.Count > 0);
```

Some people call them `empty items`. I don't know if it's official Sitecore naming or not. In Sitecore 8.1 you can force Sitecore to skip them.

You can find more information on [Enforce language version presence for items in Sitecore 8.1](http://ctor.io/enforce-language-version-presence-for-items-in-sitecore-8-1/) blog by **Kevin Brechbühl**.

Comment: Thanks Marek, I'm still not sure if I understand your response. Why would sitecore return english version of an item that is not even defined?
By same logic why wouldn't sitecore return item in German version?
I did check the database meanwhile and everything seems right, item is stored in dutch with proper value, the english (ghost) version doesn't contain any value ... still puzzled

Comment: Some people call them `empty items`. I don't know if this is official Sitecore naming. You can read more about them on Kevin Brechbühl blog http://ctor.io/enforce-language-version-presence-for-items-in-sitecore-8-1/

Comment: Thanks Marek, Kevin's link explains this issue.